# How to Bulk Inserts via TSQL without using FIELDTERMINATOR

Tags: sql-server-2000

I want to bulk insert data from .dat file. 
but the problem is the file doesn't contains any char by which i could separate different values.. 
Actually the file contain code generated by Attendance machine, the code looks like 
 
**31201201100915000100000043210001** 
**31201205301806000200000043210011** 
 
Above 2 lines are Attendance of 1 day of Employee **4321**, 
 The 1st line is entry of TimeIn & the second line is entry of TimeOut, 
details are below 
31 - Machine Code 
2012 - Year  
01 - Month 
10 - Day 
09 - Hour 
15 - Min 
0001 - In or Out (0001 for In & 0002 for Out) 
0000000061 - EmployeeCode 
0001 - Terminal No (0001 for Terminal In & 0011 for Terminal Out) 
 
can i bulk import this file ? if yes then how? can anyone tell how i can solve this problem?

**Thanks**

im using SQL server 2000 :(

Answer (score 0):

You will need to get the data into a staging table by using BULK INSERT or BCP and then parse out the columns using the SUBSTRING() and CAST()/CONVERT() functions.

Answer (score 0):

read the dat file in to a string using the Environment.Newline sperator

```
string[] Lines = System.IO.ReadAllLines("dat.file");
```

then for each line do something along the lines of

```
Int MachineCode = Lines[0].SubString(0,2);
Int Year = Lines[0].SubString(2,4);
```